# Apache / XAMPP for Windows incorrectly treats file as executable

Tags: javascript, apache, xampp, executable

I'm running `XAMPP 1.8.1` with `Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7` on my dev machine to test my projects. In both my private project and in well known Bootstrap Datepicker component I can choose any language (one of 38 in case of datepicker) **but not Polish**.

Upon deeper investigation, I found out that this is caused, because when browser tries to load locale file (`general.pl.json`, in case of my project and `bootstrap-datepicker.pl.js`, in case of Bootstrap Datepicker), server (Apache) fails with `500 Internal Server Error`.

After analyzing Apache `error.log` file, I found out, that this is happening, because Apache somehow is trying to execute this file as (probably Perl) executable script:

```
[win32:error] [pid 5128:tid 1680] [client 127.0.0.1:53455] AH02102: C:/XAMPP/htdocs/mobile/public/pg-demo-bootstrap/locales/general.pl.json is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line, referer: http://127.0.0.1/mobile/public/pg-demo-bootstrap/
[cgi:error] [pid 5128:tid 1680] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client 127.0.0.1:53455] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: C:/XAMPP/htdocs/mobile/public/pg-demo-bootstrap/locales/general.pl.json, referer: http://127.0.0.1/mobile/public/pg-demo-bootstrap/
[win32:error] [pid 5128:tid 1644] [client 127.0.0.1:53465] AH02102: C:/XAMPP/htdocs/us/ustv/assets/6dafd2fe/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pl.js is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line, referer: http://127.0.0.1/us/ustv/content/manage/update.html?id=4
[cgi:error] [pid 5128:tid 1644] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client 127.0.0.1:53465] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: C:/XAMPP/htdocs/us/ustv/assets/6dafd2fe/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pl.js, referer: http://127.0.0.1/us/ustv/content/manage/update.html?id=4
```

I did a lot of tests with changing contents and file names, using many fake files to pretend this file (Polish locale) and it all brought conlusion, that content is not a problem, only `.pl` in filename makes trouble.

Good questions are:

1. Why Apache claims, this is script, though `.pl` (Perl?) part of filename is in the middle and filename actually ends with `.js` or `.json`?
2. Why Apache **for Windows** is trying to execute Linux/Unix/Bash scripts and is looking for `#!` or `'!` characters in the first line of it?

Even better question is, how to fix this, so Apache would start treating this file as a simple Javascript, like all other locale  files? And would not attempt to execute it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf, there should be a line like:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp
```

Simply comment out this line like so:

```
#AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp
```

and restart Apache. If you want to keep the .cgi and .asp handlers, just delete .pl from the line. Perl will actually still work even if you do this.

Comment: This solves the problem, so I'm going to accept your answer and award you with well earned bounty. However, this does not answer the question -- why Apache is making these problems with files with `.pl.js` and `.pl.json` extension? Above line does says strictly about `.pl` extension files. This seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue, the previous answer did not solve the problem for me, but lead me to the Apache docs at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler which says:

> Filenames may have [multiple extensions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext) and the extension argument will
>   be compared against each of them.

The [multiple extensions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext) link lead to another section on the same page which explains that files can have multiple extensions. Ie.: `welcome.fr.html` is treated the same as `welcome.html.fr`. The order of extensions is not relevant and a filename can even contain multiple languages as in `welcome.html.en.de`. The advantage is that the defined languages are sent in the HTTP headers.

**Configure handler based on final extension only:**

```
<FilesMatch \.pl$>
SetHandler cgi-script pl
</FilesMatch>
```

To make this work I had to remove the handler for `pl` first:

```
RemoveHandler pl
```

Answer (score 2):

If appears in apache log the following message

> apache: .js is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!"

You should modify config file and use Alias instead of ScriptAlias like below :

> Alias /bugzilla/ "C:/bugzilla/"

And add the below snippet in apache config after alias line.

> ```
> <Directory "C:/bugzilla">
>     ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
>     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
>     Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
>     DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
>     AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options AuthConfig
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```

Comment: Please, correct the format and content of your answer because currently it is nearly completely not readable.

Comment: @trejder I have corrected the format and content, now it is readable, is this answer is helpful?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have upvoted your answer, because now it is all clear and fine.